# I need help to an assignment in python 3. I need to create a function that Return the nucleotide's complement

Tags: python

The function returns a message like this:

```
<function contains_sequence at 0x04020270>
```

However it return the correct anwser but that message cant be in shell.
so my code is this:

```
def contains_sequence(dna1, dna2):
    """ (str, str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if DNA sequence dna2 occurs in the DNA sequence
    dna1.

    >>> contains_sequence('ATCGGC', 'GG')
    True
    >>> contains_sequence('ATCGGC', 'GT')
    False
    """

    if dna2 in dna1:
        print (True)
    else:
        print (False)

    return contains_sequence
```

Comment: change `print(True)` to `return True`

Comment: It works for me, but I'm not using xcode. https://repl.it/FMtv

Comment: @mbomb007 It's a semantic error; the code works fine, but it does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is currently *outputing* the string `"True"` or `"False"`, not return the boolean value `True` or `False`, then unconditionally returning a reference to the function itself.

You need to return the result of the `in` comparison, which you can do with

```
def contains_sequence(dna1, dna2):
    if dna2 in dna1:
        return True
    else
        return False
```

or more idiomatically

```
def contains_sequence(dna1, dna2):
    return dna2 in dna1
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is "**Return** the nucleotide's complement", then instead of `print`ing `True` or `False`, you should `return` it, instead of the function.

```
if dna2 in dna1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Note that this could be shortened to

```
return dna2 in dna1
```

Then remove the line `return contains_sequence`.